# Accidentally moved my "Macintosh HD" -- how to do move it back?

Tags: macos, home-folder

I don't know how, but somehow I moved my Macintosh HD folder.  I must have accidentally dragged it from the sidebar of a folder, because now it's sitting in some random folder along with some files for a website building project I'm doing.

It doesn't SEEM to affect anything, except I can't move it anywhere else! I can't move or delete the folder it's sitting in either.  Here's the HD sitting inside a folder:

[image: Folder View - CLICK TO VIEW IMAGE]

What have I done?  And how can I undo it?!

[Mac OS X - El Capitan - 10.11.4]

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with moving my hard drive to another location. If I just drag it, an alias (shortcut) to the hard drive will be created wherever I drop it. If I drag it and hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>, a *copy* of the hard drive will be created wherever I drop it.

It's pretty clear in the Finder if you've made an alias:

[image]

In your case, you've made a copy of your hard drive in this location. If the location is on an external hard drive, you can eject the drive to verify that you don't need this copy.

You're probably having trouble deleting it because the copy has preserved the file permissions, and many files will be owned by system accounts. If you try to delete the copy you should be prompted for an administrator's name and password, but otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: That's a very well-explained answer, and thank you for that.  But I don't think that could be what happened in this case.  That's because my hard drive is only 1TB, and as shown in the image, my "Macintosh HD" folder is almost 900GB.  The folder it now shows up in, "Raw Files", is **not** on an external drive, so there isn't _room_ to have made a copy of my entire hard drive in that folder.  Finder won't let me eject, and I still can't delete the folder or change its name, let alone delete the copy...or whatever it is.

Comment: (continued) It might also be worth noting that "Macintosh HD" still shows up as the startup volume in the "My iMac" section of Finder.  If it turns out that I actually moved it (instead of copied it), where SHOULD it have been to begin with?  I have no idea where to return it...but it definitely doesn't belong in my website project's folder.